# How can I alter input in <TextInput /> while people type?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to alter the value of a `TextInput` in React Native, so that no matter what, it always forces them to eventually enter the string 'Black'. When they enter a different character, for example Bl**e**, it would change it to Bl**a** instead.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

var matchesinput = ['B', 'Bl', 'Bla', 'Blac', 'Black'];
var matches = ['b', 'bl', 'bla', 'blac', 'black'];

var newText = '';

return(
  <>
    <TextInput
      style = {{...objstyle, ...color}}
      value = {text}
      onChangeText={newInput => {
        if (matches.indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          setText(newInput);
        }
        else if (newInput != '' && newInput.length < 6) {
          newText = matchesinput[newInput.length - 1];
          setText(newText);
        } 
        else {
          setText(newInput);
        }
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```

It seems to work for the first character, but the next incorrect character you enter causes it to glitch and jump to 'Bla', and then straight to 'Black', or sometimes it just continues past 'Black' and then disappears.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What should happen if they move the cursor say to the beginning and type an additional letter?

Comment: Why are you using the same name `text` as a state variable and change event prop?

Comment: Say they typed 'Bl' and then added 'eBl', it should just turn into 'Bla'.

Comment: Using `text` for both didn't actually make any difference to the outcome, so I just left it as that. Should I change it?

Comment: @Joseph What would you do if you want to use the state variable inside the callback (onChangeText) function?

Comment: I am using it in the onChangeText function, to get it's length and to pass to setText. I've changed it's name to `newInput`, but it doesn't change functionality, as I said before.

Comment: Change `text.toLowerCase()` also

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any complicated matching. Just take the length of the entered string and set state with the first part of `'Black'` of the same length:

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
const handleChange = (newText) => setText("Black".substring(0, newText.length));

return <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={handleChange} />;
```

Note: If `text.length` exceeds the length of `'Black'` it will just result in `'Black'`. So it will not be possible to enter more than 5 letters.

Also see [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

[image: Edit silly-hooks-k6cyq]

Comment: This has the same problem - If I enter 'Ba' it changes to 'Bl', but if I then enter another e to make 'Ble', it changes it to 'Black', when it's supposed to be 'Bla'.                                ```onChangeText={ newInput => { setText('Black'.substring(0, newInput.length)); }}```

Comment: @Joseph Yeah I definded the handler as a separate method to keep the example simple and free of irrelevant stuff. But sure, you can also inline it like that. You could also move that definition into your component and do `onChangeText={handleChange}`.

Comment: I agree that it simplifies the code and makes it look nicer, but it doesn't actually fix the issue (although I will start doing it like this in the future)

Comment: @Joseph Then the handler doesn't get the text as that clearly should work. See this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hooks-k6cyq?file=/src/App.js . Does the handler even get called with the text as the argument? Where does `TextInput` come  from?

Comment: `TextInput` is a core component of React Native - I'm pretty sure you're just using React, although I just started with React Native (was using JS before) and so I might be wrong. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Comment: @Joseph This sandbox is to demonstrate the logic of the handler. It works just as well with react-native. Did you make sure you reloaded your application?

Comment: @Joseph I've updated the sandbox to use react-native just to demonstrate it works exactly the same there.

Comment: It still doesn't work, even when I just copy and paste it over in it's entirety, it still doesn't work, despite being fine in the sandbox. It might be something to do with expo and the way the JS is ported to a device. Thanks for all the help anyway!